# Visual studio Code, error terminal pipenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

This is my first question. I have a problem, I've installed pipenv with:

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

When I do this in a terminal in Ubuntu, I have not problem. But if I try use it in Visual Studio I get the error:

> not found...you can install, sudo apt install pipenv

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're running, as well as the contents of your environment.

Comment: Thanks for all. when I run in a tab of VSC pipenv --python3.7 return pipenv not found... always return pipenv not found.... but when do it in ubuntu terminal i have not problem, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to give clearer and more complete explanations so that your problem can be solved faster and more accurately. But for now I suggest the following solution.(i think your problem is in setting-up pipenv in VS Code).
if the pipenv doesn't known in VSCode, take this action:

go to the *terminal tab* in VS-Code and simply ran:

```
1- pipenv --python 3.x (that x is your python version)
2- pipenv install
```

What I wrtoe above, VS Code not picking up the virtualenv by default. 
you can fix that. (solution below).

add these 3 lines to your local ***settings.json*** file that will be fix everything:

```
1-   {
2-       "python.venvPath": "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/",
3-       "python.pythonPath": "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/ENV-NAME/bin/python",
4-        "python.jediEnabled": true,
5-    }
```

After adding these and restart VS Code, probably you able to navigate around the project.

---

**Pro tip:** An easy way to figure out your python Path is to type the following command in the terminal where there’s an active pipenv virtual env:

```
pipenv --py
```